# Create groups based on multiple DateTime comparison

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I am attempting to create a column based and populate it with a valued based on the comparison of one date column with three other date columns.

An example of the DataFrame `df` is shown below. All dates shown are already converted to `pd.to_datetime`, which resulted in a number of `NaT` values as the individual has not progressed

```
    1st_date     2nd_date        3rd_date     action_date
    2015-10-05   NaT             NaT          2015-12-03 
    2015-02-27   2015-03-14      2015-03-15   2015-04-08 
    2015-03-07   2015-03-27      2015-03-28   2015-03-27 
    2015-01-05   2015-01-20      2015-01-21   2015-05-20 
    2015-01-05   2015-01-20      2015-01-21   2015-09-16 
    2015-05-23   2015-06-18      2015-06-19   2015-07-01 
    2015-03-03   NaT             NaT          2015-07-23 
    2015-03-03   NaT             NaT          2015-11-14 
    2015-06-05   2015-06-19      2015-06-20   2015-10-24 
    2015-10-08   2015-10-21      2015-10-22   2015-12-22
```

I am attempting to create a fifth column containing the result (or group) of the comparison of the `action_date` column with the previous three date columns `1st_date, 2nd_date, 3rd_date`.

I am attempting to populate a fifth column called `action_group` with the a string assigning each date to a group.

Pseudo-code for the potential function (and expected output) is as : `if action_date > 1st_date and < 2nd_date then action_group = '1st_action_group'`

The same comparison is needed for `action_date`, `2nd_date` and `3rd_date`, which would result in an output of `2nd_action_group` in the `action_group` column.

Finally if `action_date` is greater than `3rd_date`, `action_group` would be assigned a value of `3rd_action_group`.

An example of the expected output is shown below.

```
1st_date     2nd_date        3rd_date     action_date  action_group
2015-10-05   NaT             NaT          2015-12-03   1st_action_group
2015-02-27   2015-03-14      2015-03-15   2015-04-08   3rd_action_group
2015-03-07   2015-03-27      2015-03-28   2015-03-27   2nd_action_group
2015-01-05   2015-01-20      2015-01-21   2015-05-20   3rd_action_group
2015-01-05   2015-01-20      2015-01-21   2015-09-16   3rd_action_group
2015-05-23   2015-06-18      2015-06-19   2015-07-01   3rd_action_group
2015-03-03   NaT             NaT          2015-07-23   1st_action_group
2015-03-03   NaT             NaT          2015-11-14   1st_action_group
2015-06-05   2015-06-19      2015-06-20   2015-10-24   3rd_action_group
2015-10-08   2015-10-21      2015-10-22   2015-12-22   3rd_action_group
```

Any assistance that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['action_group'] = np.where(df['action_date']>df['3rd_date'], 
                              '3rd_action_group', 
                               np.where(((df['action_date'] >= df['2nd_date'])&(df['action_date']<df['3rd_date'])), 
                                          '2nd_action_group', 
                                          '1st_action_group'))
```

You can just stack 2 np.where's to get your desired results.

```
    1st_date    2nd_date    3rd_date    action_date action_group
0   2015-10-05     NaT          NaT     2015-12-03  1st_action_group
1   2015-02-27  2015-03-14  2015-03-15  2015-04-08  3rd_action_group
2   2015-03-07  2015-03-27  2015-03-28  2015-03-27  2nd_action_group
3   2015-01-05  2015-01-20  2015-01-21  2015-05-20  3rd_action_group
4   2015-01-05  2015-01-20  2015-01-21  2015-09-16  3rd_action_group
5   2015-05-23  2015-06-18  2015-06-19  2015-07-01  3rd_action_group
6   2015-03-03     NaT          NaT     2015-07-23  1st_action_group
7   2015-03-03     NaT          NaT     2015-11-14  1st_action_group
8   2015-06-05  2015-06-19  2015-06-20  2015-10-24  3rd_action_group
9   2015-10-08  2015-10-21  2015-10-22  2015-12-22  3rd_action_group
```

Comment: Using `np.select` may be better than nested `np.where` ?